# How to use PTHREAD_SETAFFINITY_NP correctly?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I am working on a program which have  computationa based on a lot of data .So I created two threads.Their work is similar,but their data are different. I do this using the code below:

```
status1 = pthread_create(&pthread1,NULL,func_1,(void*)t1);
if(status1 != 0)
    printf("pthread1 is not created sucessfully!\n");
status = pthread_create(&pthread2,NULL,func_2,(void*)t2);
if(status != 0)
    printf("pthread2 is not created successfully!\n");
```

func_1 and func_2 are similar.
Then I want to dispatch them to different processors.So I use PTHREAD_SETAFFINITY_NP,but it failed.
My codes are below.

```
void func_1()
{
    cpu_set_t mask1;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask1);
    CPU_SET(1,&mask1);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(),sizeof(mask1),&mask1);
    for (j = 0; j < cpu_num; j++) {
    if (CPU_ISSET(j, &mask1)) 
    {
        //printf("thread %lld is running in processor %d\n", pthread_self(), j);
         cout<<"thread "<<pthread_self()<<" is running in processor "<< j <<endl;
    }
}
void func_2()
{
    cpu_set_t mask2;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask2);
    CPU_SET(0,&mask2);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(),sizeof(mask2),&mask2);
    for (j = 0; j < cpu_num; j++) {
    if (CPU_ISSET(j, &mask2)) 
    {
        //printf("thread %lld is running in processor %d\n", pthread_self(), j);
         cout<<"thread "<<pthread_self()<<" is running in processor "<< j <<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    status1 = pthread_create(&pthread1,NULL,func_1,(void*)t1);
    if(status1 != 0)
        printf("pthread1 is not created sucessfully!\n");
    status = pthread_create(&pthread2,NULL,func_2,(void*)t2);
    if(status != 0)
        printf("pthread2 is not created successfully!\n");
    pthread_join(pthread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(pthread2,NULL);
    ......
}
```

But to my surprised, result comes out like this:

```
thread 7369190208 is running in processor 0
thread 3065830208 is running in processor 0
```

How can I do to dispatch each thread to a specific processor?

EDIT:
I want to dispatch threads to different processors because if they two are running on one processor,it is like serial.How to dispatch?as shown below:
serial:
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i ++)
        do something;
I use two threads,then it becomes like:

pthread1:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i += 2)
    do something;
```

pthread2:

```
for(i = 1 ; i < N ; i += 2)
    do something;
```

and the **speedup** can be nearly 2

Comment: Your `printf` is assuming that `pthread_t` is the same as `long long`. You'll get undefined behaviour if that's not the case.

Comment: You mean `printf("thread %lld is running in processor %d\n", pthread_self(), j);`? pthread_self() return the thread's id,it is `long long`,yes? Maybe I haven't understood what you mean but What troubles me is to find out what caused my wrong dispatch. :)

Comment: The type is `pthread_t`, which is whatever your OS defines it to be (`unsigned long` on mine, yours may differ). Either convert it to a known type to match the `printf` specifier, or (since you've tagged the question C++) use the type-safe `cout`.

Comment: Oh,I understand it,thanks.And can you help me with my another problem?(I will correct it)